# Printing from gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot, coreldraw

Pls I have drawn a graph using gnuplot.
All the margins are set to zero.

I saved the output with pngcairo and tried printing it from Corel draw x3 on an a3 sheet. I want the size to be 250mm vertical and 350mm horizontal.
However, some of the grid sizes short by some few millimetres reducing the entire vertical and horizontal sizes by some millimetres.![enter image description here][1]
   Our project also relies on technical precision. I'll be happy if someone can help me know what I'm doing wrongly.

Comment: Hi, please edit the post to include some code of what you tried and what you want to achieve.

Comment: PNG as you certainly know is a raster format. You need a DPI to convert into physical size. If the question involves Coreldraw, tag it to get a higher chance of answer

Comment: OK. I have done so. I have the image but my credit restricts me from posting it.

Comment: So A3 is 297 x 420 mm, so there should be space.  What is the DPI of the png file generated?  If you don't know: How many pixels wide is the image?  How many pixels between the grid lines?  Maybe there are margins generated you did not successfully suppress, or maybe the lines are too thick.  Hard to tell.

Comment: Yes u are right. I chosed  line with 2 for x and yticd. Then line with 1 for mx and mytics. After making both the minor and major tics line with one, it became normal. Thanks alot.